# Bootstrap não inicializando

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-3, flask

Estou começando com Flask e estou usando o Bootstrap 3.3.7, para isso peguei o código exemplo da navbar no site deles, porem quando inicio o index o nav bar não funciona: [image: O navbar não carrega] e o botão está parecido com o do bootstrap 4, porem ja baixei várias vezes o bootstrap 3.3.7 e continua do mesmo jeito.

Screenshots do index.html:
[image: inicio index]

[image: meio index]
[image: final index]

Comment: Tente isto jovem :     <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/bootstrap.css') }}">

Você pode abrir as ferramentas de desenvolvimento do navegador e ir na aba 'Resources' para conferir se o arquivo foi ou não importado

Comment: Não mudou nada. mas ta dando esse error: `Uncaught Error: Bootstrap tooltips require Tether (http://tether.io/)` mas eu nunca precisei de mais nada para fazer o bootstrap funcionar antes.

Comment: ao inves de utilizar os arquivos locais, utilizei o cdn e funcionou ai fui pesquisar sobre esse erro e vi que é relacionado ao bootstrap 4, como se os arquivos que baixei fossem do 4, mas eu fui no site e baixei o 3.3.7 so que não vai.